# Error starting app on Heroku using Devise

Tags: heroku, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1

When pushing a new app to heroku, then running `heroku rake db:migrate` I get the following error:

```
heroku rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
```

Does anyone have any idea why it's asking for postgresql? In my gemfile the only db gem I'm using is sqlite.

This app is using Devise for authentication, that's the only gem out of the ordinary in the app's gemfile. On a sidenote, when I attempt to follow the advice, bundler throws:

```
Could not find gem 'activerecord-postgresql-adapter (>= 0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't use sqlite3 on Heroku, you have to use their Postgres or use your own external Db.

In your gemfile do

```
group :development do
 gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
 gem 'pg'
end
```

to let you use sqlite3 locally and postgres on Heroku.

Comment: Thanks @John. This must be some new requirement? I have apps running pre 3.1 that only specify sqlite3 in the gemfile with no issues at all.

Comment: could be - the older stacks may have had the libraries available so the native extension could be built. But not on Cedar. But a word of warning - you would be much better of using Postgres locally if you're deploying to Postgres on Heroku.